# Angular project update from v8 to v10 makes bundles horribly large

Tags: angular, refactoring, bundle, filesize

I've started working on stable 3-years old (relatively) large project and the idea is to clean up dependencies, update Angular, refactor some things etc. In that process, I have made changes:

- On some places I have put Angular Material components and removed some Nebular components,
- moved from Angular 8 to Angular 10,
- activated Ivy renderer.

Application module bundle rose up from 13 MB stat size, which I'm aware that is already high, to horrific 88 MB. The point which I have found suspicious is that we have circa 100 components that inherit base component, and that base component (of course) has some dependencies. Those 100 components rose up from 10-50 kB to 800-900 kB. Also, those components are declared in one module, which is transitively imported into app module.

What I have tried, but without success:

- moved from lodash to lodash-es and optimised those imports
- turned off Ivy renderer

I'm trying to understand: what bad practice / anti-pattern would cause an issue like this? I understand that all those components are declared transitively into app module, but it was like this before, also. On the other hand, that doesn't excuse that large size of one subcomponent.

I can provide additional diagnostic data if needed.

Comment: Try running builds for both versions (i.e. 8 and 10) with the [--stats-json](https://angular.io/cli/build) flag, and then analyze this data e.g. using [webpack-bundle-analyzer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer). Otherwise, it's hard to really say anything without knowing the project settings, packages used, build pipeline, set up of modules, etc. But I assume the code is proprietary and there's not much you can share.

Comment: Exactly - can't share. I can share the graphs, little bit censored, but nothing besides that. I have made that analysis. that's how I have the info what got bigger size etc. Anyway, thanks for good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out the problem and the solution:

Every subcomponent has the same SCSS file in `styleUrls` property. That SCSS file imports the main SCSS theme file (which is, by the way, already globally imported). Because of that, main SCSS file (which is freaking large) is imported ~100 times. With removing that import, module bundle lowered from 88 MB to 20 MB. I guess there are also other places to do refactor like this, and my wild naive guess is that the old bundler/renderer took this into account when building the files, while the new one is not that forgiving.